# Reactjs expand only 1 list item from lists rendered via map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list-items in react project which are rendered by map function to the UI

Here is the code below

parent component

```
export default function PackageDetails({ newArray, packages }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  const setOpenFunction = () => {
    setShow(!show)
  }
  return (
    <Row>    
      <NonRecommendedPackage
        setOpen={setOpenFunction}
        show={show}
        packages={packages}
      />
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Child components

```
export default function RecommendedPackage({ setOpen, show ,packages}) {
  return (
    packages.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <div className="not-recommended-packages" id={index}>
            <div className="main-results-row">

              <div className="package-item package-price">{item.price} € /ano</div>



              <button className="plus-icon-button">
                <span className="plus-text">+</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            {show && <div className="main-info">THIS DIV GETS DISPLAYED WHEN USER CLICKS ON ANY LIST ITEM</div>}
          </div>

          
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

So like my list has 10 item and if i select the item at position 2 , only i want that div to expand and show my "main-info" div which is rendered by condition in the above code

```
{show && <div className="main-info">THIS DIV GETS DISPLAYED WHEN USER CLICKS ON ANY LIST ITEM</div>}
```

Comment: Maybe each of your list item can have its own expand/collapse state and then you can toggle that using the click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `const [show, setShow] = useState(false)` to childComponent class *RecommendPackage*. This way every child would have their own state whether to show or now.

```
export default function PackageDetails({ newArray, packages }) {
  return (
    <Row>    
     {packages.map((item, index) => 
      <RecommendedPackage
        key={index}
        item={item}
      />
      )}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Now in your child component do

```
export default function RecommendedPackage({ item}) {
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

      return (
          <div className="not-recommended-packages" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
            <div className="main-results-row">

              <div className="package-item package-price">{item.price} € /ano</div>



              <button className="plus-icon-button">
                <span className="plus-text">+</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            {show && <div className="main-info">THIS DIV GETS DISPLAYED WHEN USER CLICKS ON ANY LIST ITEM</div>}
          </div>
     )
}
```